# Autossh ask for password when running with sudo (or from upstart)

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, upstart

I have an upstart job `/etc/init/tunnel.conf`:

```
description "SSH Tunnel"

start on (net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel[016]

respawn

exec autossh -nNT -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -R 12345:localhost:22 myuser@myserver
```

When I look at the `/var/log/upstart/tunnel.log`:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

but if I try from terminal

```
autossh -R 12345:localhost:22 myuser@myserver
```

It connects to myserver without asking me for password (I have copied the SSH keys)

When I run it using `sudo`:

```
sudo autossh -R 12345:localhost:22 myuser@myserver
```

It asks me for myserver password, so I guess this is the problem I have with the upstart job. Why SSH is asking me for password we I run it as a root?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `autossh` invoked by **sudo** or init process,  `autossh` use identity/ssh-keys file provided by **root** user (e.g. `/root/.ssh/sshkeys`). When you try run `autossh` from terminal, maybe you use **non-root** user. Thus, `autossh` use identity/ssh-keys file provided by that user (e.g `/home/non-root/.ssh/sshkeys`).

To get expected behavior, you can provided identity file in `tunnel.conf`. To do that, modify last line to

```
exec autossh -nNT -i /home/non-root/.ssh/sshkeys -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -R 12345:localhost:22 myuser@myserver
```

More info in [Autossh with Ubuntu Upstart](https://www.async.fi/2013/07/autossh-with-ubuntu-upstart/)

Comment: Thanks now it works, besides teere is a problem with the command you wrote, the -o is misplaced should be `exec autossh -nNT -i /home/non-root/.ssh/sshkeys -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -R 12345:localhost:22 myuser@myserver`

Comment: Now I have the problem with the remote computer previously I connected but now I cant `$ ssh leo@localhost -p 54321 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: masegaloeh, great answer! Why use `exec` btw?